How to get the LVCMOS configuration?
I am using HMC7044 IC for clock generation in my application design.
Below is the evaluation schematic of HMC7044.

HMC7044 has 14 clock outputs (7 DCLK outputs and 7 SYSREF outputs) and is mentioned in the datasheet that the outputs can be configured as CML, LVDS, LVPECL, LVCMOS.
In the evaluation schematic, the outputs are connected such that by changing certain values of resistors or capacitors or by replacing some passives we can achieve different configurations (LVDS/LVPECL/CML/LVCMOS).
I have found the below reference regarding different configurations in the userguide-826.

In my application I want to use OSCOUT pins as CMOS pins as I don't have the feasibility to give LVDS. I would be using the signal on the OSCOUT only for testing and debugging.
My query is how to change the configuration given for OSCOUT in evaluation schematic to CMOS form?
Link for user-guide:
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/user-guides/EK1HMC7044LP10B_UG-826.pdf
Link for evaluation schematic:
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/evaluation-documentation/HMC7044_EVAL_Schematic.pdf
Link for datasheet:
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc7044.pdf
Also, can anyone kindly explain clearly how to transform from one configuration to other in the outputs as I am having a confusion regarding it?

The HMC7044 datasheet shows there is the OSCOUTx/OSCOUTx Driver Control register in which bits [5:4] select the Oscillator output driver mode:

The HMC7044 has a SPI interface used to read or write the control registers.
The EVAL-HMC7044 looks to come with a USB Interface Board, which presumably implements a USB to SPI interface to allow the HMC7044 evaluation software which runs on a PC to modify the the HMC7044 control registers via SPI.

But Hardware wise, externally what should i connect to the OSCOUT pins. What value of resistors and capacitors are to be connected and how
